# Why can't I center these links?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem here with my links on my navbar..
I used so many tags, like text-align,  wich you'll see in my codes right now, and still not in the center, can you help me to fix this out? 
I'm counting on you guys! 
Thanks

here's my bin -> http://jsbin.com/towemisa/1/
you can click on "edit bin" o the right top corner

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="header">
        <h1> Evergreen </h1>
        <h3> Free information for you! </h3>
        <div class="sublinks">
            <a href="index.html">Home  |</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact  |</a>
            <a href="login.html">Login  |</a>
            <a href="register.html">Register</a> <br>
            <h3 style="color:white">Search</h3>
            <input type="text" size="30"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="linkspart">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
        <a href="download.html">Download</a>
        <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    </div> 
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color:#b2b200;
}

.page {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
}

.header {
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
}

.header h1 {
    color:white;
    float:left;
    left: 45px;
}

.header h3 {
    color:grey;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
}

.header .sublinks {
    width:400px;
    height:90px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:65px;
}

.header .sublinks a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    top: 10px;
}

.header .sublinks a:hover {
    color:black;
}

.header .sublinks h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

.header .sublinks input {
    position: relative;
    top: 17px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.linkspart {
    width:1000px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.linkspart a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Add the CSS and HTML to the question, please.

Comment: its on the bin, but sure, i'll do it

Comment: most of codes I used from an youtube professor (recording on classroom), an others codes I did it myself, since I'm a beginner (1month hmtl css), I use the codes I learnt since then, even if they are like 20 or 30, I use them, but what you say it's true, if I want to learn more about CSS and HTML i must buy a book or pay someone to teach me, but like I don't have niether, I'm tryint to improve alone xD thanks for the advice

Comment: Here's the approach that I would recommend.  First, start with a sketch.  You can do a drawing by hand or digitally.  It does not need to be a work of art - just somewhat of a close representation of the page that you are trying to build.  Second, create your HTML code first for that page.  Then, post the sketch and the code here or other forums and ask for comments on how your HTML structure can be improved.  You'll get a ton of useful suggestions and you and others will learn a lot.  Third, once you solidify your HTML structure, then proceed with CSS.

Comment: The solution that you picked is a quick patch on top of an unstable HTML & CSS structure and the links in the navigation bar are not really centered; they are more skewed to the right.  At any rate, keeping hacking away at it and bit by bit HTML and CSS will become a second nature to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
.header .sublinks {
    width:400px;
    height:90px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:65px;
}
```

Edited Code:

```
.header .sublinks {
    width:400px;
    height:90px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
```

You have `margin-top:20px;` and `margin-left:65px;` set which is why you can not `center` the links.
Just remove the `margin-left` and `margin-right`

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YpLa8/

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because you set the left margin of the wrapping div 
since you have set a width it will work fine if you set the `margin` to `auto`

```
.header .sublinks {
width:400px;
height:90px;
float:right;
position:relative;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: it works o.O nice, thanks
but can you be more especific? what was really my error? i set up these margin's to be more align to the "Evergreen" Heading

Comment: as i mentioned in my first reply, you set the margin of the wrapping div. which means it'll push be pushed exactly that far from the left side - however you can set your top margin to keep it relative to the Heading